# Integrals exercise.

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How can I calculate the following integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\lfloor x\rfloor e^{-3x}\ \text{d}x$$
One way to do it is to express the integral as a geometric sum, but I don't know how to do that part, some help.

Comment: Could you please add a little more context? How did you know a solution involves a geometric sum yet don't know the required steps? Have you tried any other methods?

Comment: I have not tried other methods, I am just beginning to see this issue. And I know that it is done with geometric sums since it is the subject that I am beginning to see now.

Comment: I see - would you be able to add your current steps into the question? That way, people will be able to correct any potential mistake as well as help guide you better

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\int_{n}^{n+1} e^{-x}\,dx =\sum_{n=0}^\infty n \left(e^{-n}-e^{-(n+1)}\right)$$And you can finish now.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_0^\infty n\int_n^{n+1}e^{-3x}dx=\frac{1}{3}\sum_0^\infty n(e^{-3n}-e^{-3(n+1)})=$$\frac{1-e^{-3}}{3}\sum_0^\infty ne^{-3n}$

$ne^{-nx}=-\frac{d}{dx}e^{-nx}$.  Sum to get $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{-1}{1-e^{-x}}=\frac{e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-x})^2}$.

Let $x=3$ to get final result $\frac{e^{-3}}{3(1-e^{-3})}=\frac{1}{3(e^3-1)}$.

Comment: Since series is convergent, you could regroup as $a_n=\left(ne^{-3n}-(n+1)e^{-3(n+1)}\right)+\frac 1{e^3} e^{-3n}$ to benefit the telescoping and spare the use of derivative.

Comment: @zwin You're right!.